# Alter from console.writeline to dataset linq to xml

Tags: xml, dataset, linq-to-xml

How do I alter this code so that I am writing out the values to the same dataset rather than to the Console.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                {


           string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*");  
              foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)  

                {
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
                    var query = from x in doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib")
                                select new
                                {

                                    MaxChild = x.Descendants("Max"),
                                    MinChild = x.Descendants("Min")
                                };

                    foreach (var x in query)
                    {
                        foreach (var nextLevel in x.MaxChild)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value);
                        }
                        foreach (var nextLevel in x.MinChild)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value + "\n");
                        }

                    }



                    var query2 = from y in doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib")

                                 select new
                                 {

                                     MaxChild = y.Descendants("Max"),
                                     MinChild = y.Descendants("Min")

                                 };


                    foreach (var y in query2)
                    {
                        foreach (var nextLevel in y.MaxChild)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value);
                        }
                        foreach (var nextLevel in y.MinChild)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value + "\n");
                        }

                        var query3 = from z in doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib")

                                     select new
                                     {

                                         MaxChild = z.Descendants("Max"),
                                         MinChild = z.Descendants("Min")
                                     };

                        foreach (var z in query3)
                        {
                            foreach (var nextLevel in z.MaxChild)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value);
                            }
                            foreach (var nextLevel in z.MinChild)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("" + nextLevel.Value + "\n");
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to put the XML data into a DataSet, you maybe able to use the built-in XML capabilities of the DataSet.  It depends on the format of the XML (you can write XML with a DataSet also):

```
        DataSet MyDataSet = new DataSet();

        MyDataSet.ReadXml("C:\FileName.xml");
```